# prove $f$ is a constant

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Lets's say we have a differentiable function

$f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$

with

$f^\prime\equiv0$

How do I show that

$f\equiv C$

by using the mean value theorem?

Comment: Have you searched before asking? Key terms: constant, derivative zero, mean value.

Comment: Yes I did but it seems that i may have had a different way of thinking and didn't notice that a similar question has been asked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $x\in (a,b]$, we have
$$\tag{1} f(x)-f(a)=f'(\zeta)\cdot(x-a)\mbox{ for some }\zeta\in (a,x)$$
by the [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Formal_statement). Now, since $f'\equiv 0$, it follows from $(1)$ that
$$f(x)-f(a)=0,$$
that is
$f(x)=f(a)$.

Answer (score 4):

One approach is to prove by contradiction (or contrapositive).

Suppose that $f$ is not constant. Then, there exists a $b' \in [a,b]$ such that $f(b') \neq f(a)$.  Apply the mean value theorem on the interval $[a,b']$.  What do you conclude?

Comment: I seem to struggle with the mean value theorem.
$\exists b'\in [a,b] : f(b') \neq f(a)$
If I apply the mean value theorem now i have :
$\frac{f(b')-f(a)} {b'-a}$
How do I continue?

Comment: What does the mean value theorem say, in words?  The statement "I have $\frac{f(b')-f(a)}{b'-a}$" doesn't mean anything to me as written.  But what does the mean value theorem tell you **about** that number?

Comment: It says that there is a point which has the average slope of the whole function in the $[a,b]$ , doesn't it?

Comment: Something like that.  The mean value theorem states ***there exists** a point $c \in [a,b']$ such that $f'(c) = \frac{f(b') - f(a)}{b' - a} \neq 0$.*

Comment: I think i got it. Thank you :)